# Do the rocket bombs in 1984 only ever strike prole quarters?

Tags: george-orwell, nineteen-eighty-four

Relatively in the middle of chapter 5 in “1984” it says:

> In some ways she was far more acute than Winston, and
> far less susceptible to Party propaganda. Once when he
> happened in some connexion to mention the war against
> Eurasia, she startled him by saying casually that in her opinion the war was not happening. The rocket bombs which fell
> daily on London were probably fired by the Government
> of Oceania itself, ‘just to keep people frightened’. This was
> an idea that had literally never occurred to him.

I remember having read that Julia's presumption was likely true because “the rocket bombs only ever hit prole quarters”.

However, when deliberately looking for a passage that would imply this, I did not find anything.

Am I misremembering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may mean nothing more than that the only rocket bomb attacks described in the book itself as close to Winston occur when Winston goes for a walk in the prole quarters.

> There was a roar
> that seemed to make the pavement heave; a shower of light objects pattered
> on to his back. When he stood up he found that he was covered with
> fragments of glass from the nearest window.

and while he and Julia are slipping off for a tryst, possibly in prole quarters

> They were passing in silence down a side-street (Julia would never speak when they were away from the main streets) when there was a deafening roar, the earth heaved, and the air darkened, and Winston found himself lying on his side, bruised and terrified. A rocket bomb must have dropped quite near at hand.

Also, the proles have a casual term for them, as Party Members do not, which could indicate a familiarity. From the same scene:

> 'Steamer' was a nickname which, for some reason, the proles applied to
> rocket bombs. Winston promptly flung himself on his face. The proles were
> nearly always right when they gave you a warning of this kind. They seemed
> to possess some kind of instinct which told them several seconds in advance
> when a rocket was coming, although the rockets supposedly travelled faster
> than sound.

Other descriptions are far off that could have landed in prole quarters

> Somewhere far away a rocket bomb exploded with a dull, reverberating roar. About twenty or thirty of them a week were falling on London at present.

> The rocket bombs crashed oftener than ever, and sometimes in the far distance there were enormous explosions which no one could explain and about which there were wild rumours.

> As though to harmonize with the general mood, the rocket bombs had been
> killing larger numbers of people than usual. One fell on a crowded film
> theatre in Stepney, burying several hundred victims among the ruins. The
> whole population of the neighbourhood turned out for a long, trailing
> funeral which went on for hours and was in effect an indignation meeting.
> Another bomb fell on a piece of waste ground which was used as a playground
> and several dozen children were blown to pieces

> Somewhere in remote distance a rocket bomb thundered.

That is, the conclusion that the rockets land only in prole quarters has some evidence but not conclusive proof.